# Symfony2 Deployment

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently installing a Symfony project on my PC having the same specifications yet it has been giving me the following error whenever I'm running the app in the dev environment:

> **Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.**

I thought by just simply clearing the cache it would solve everything. I even tried to do the suggested process that might solve the problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135572/deploying-symfony2-app-getting-fosuserbundle-errors). Yet it's still the same. I already cleared the cache(console and manual), created a new user by running this command:

`php app\console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssw0rd`

And even these:

`php app\console doctrine:schema:update --force`

`php app\console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`

What else do you think I should do?

---

**Add-ons**

When I run it with the prod environment, I receive the following errors and warnings:

> **Warning**: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Matrix\MatrixUserBundle\Entity\User' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo.php on line 869
>
> **Notice**: unserialize(): Error at offset 46 of 47 bytes in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo.php
>   on line 869
>
> **Fatal error:** __clone method called on non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo.php
>   on line 872

Comment: Need more info that that. How are you accessing the page? where is this error showing up? what version of symfony?

Comment: I'm using symfony2, I'm only new to this framework and still have a limited knowledge about this. This error appears whenever I attempt to log into the system. I'm using xampp by the way.

Comment: do you login with app_dev.php in the URL? do you have any other errors in your server logs?

Comment: @Chausser I added something

Comment: Have you installed the vendor libs? `composer install` ?

Comment: You better ask some current project developer how to do that. There is no a uniform "how to install an arbitrary symfony2 based project" since every project is unique.

Comment: @Chausser I've already installed the vendor libraries, still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue where upgrading to PHP 5.6 breaks the `unserialize` function. I encountered this using the JMSSerializerBundle in Symfony. It is fixed in the current master of JMSSerializerBundle so I fixed this problem by changing composer.json to use

`"jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master"`

It may be that updating your doctrine version to use master in composer.json as mentioned here:

[Symfony 2.5.3 and PHP 5.6.0: incompatibility issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614298/symfony-2-5-3-and-php-5-6-0-incompatibility-issues)